# Logging in grinder

Tags: load-testing, stress-testing, grinder

I am testing a webapp, i want to log all http request and response, how do i do that?
 
I am just writing

> log = grinder.logger.info 
>        def page15(self):
>       """GET COPSApp (request 1501)."""
>       result = request1501.GET('/webdynpro/call_agent_dtop-login_wd/COPSApp')
>     log("-----------------------------------")
>       return result

But it is not logging. what do i need to do in order to login

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Request Logging**

Grinder will normally log all of your HTTP requests. So at least for the request logging, the default behaviour may be good enough for you.  Look for a log file with a name like

```
<hostname>-0.log
```

In this file, you'll see your requests, plus the server response codes.

If you want to explicitly log your http request from your code, you'll need to use a slightly different pattern than the one you are currently using.

```py
    request1501.setUrl('/webdynpro/call_agent_dtop-login_wd/COPSApp')
    response1501=request1501.GET()
    log(request1501.getUrl())
```

**Response Logging**

When logging the HTTP response, you need to deal with the body and the headers separately.  Based on your code example above, you could log the body like this:

```py
    log(response1501.getText())
```

There are a couple of ways you can log the HTTP response headers.  The easiest way would be to dump them all to the log in a single statement, like this:

```py
    log(response1501.toString())
```

To get an idea of the other options for logging http response headers, and the different things you can access separately, see the HTTPResponse API here:

http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/script-javadoc/HTTPClient/HTTPResponse.html

**Login**

In your question, you also asked "*what do i need to do in order to login*".  I assume this is a typo, and that what you really mean is how do you write stuff to the log.  To do an actual login, you need to submit a username and password, typically via HTTP post.  Grinder can do this for you easily enough, but that topic should be addressed in a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I came to know many thing by your answer, I am still facing problem that i am not able to log anything even simple text like my name etc. *log = grinder.logger.info* i have wiritten this in starting of my .py file 
and than written *log("-----------------------------------")* in some method . Do i need to import some package or sth else .
I just want to log a simple text in some of calling function .  Thanks a lot

Comment: And in my .py file start with <br>
from net.grinder.script import Test<br>
from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder<br>
from net.grinder.plugin.http import HTTPPluginControl,<br> HTTPRequest<br>
from HTTPClient import NVPair<br>
connectionDefaults = HTTPPluginControl.getConnectionDefaults()<br>
httpUtilities = HTTPPluginControl.getHTTPUtilities()<br>

Comment: is it possible (for debugging purposes) to control the log output and have grinder log to e.g. '<hostname>.log' all the time?

Comment: for me it works like this:
`from net.grinder.script.Grinder.grinder import logger as log`
`log.info("-----------")`